# Wrong Link on Facebook and wrong open graph but good meta property

Tags: facebook

My web site www.jeancharlesbarthelet.com has good meta . (I checked)

When I tried to share on Facebook, there is no image, no description.

I tried one hundred times the debug tool !! (for one month)

Nothing works.

I am very worried because lots of people are sharing my news at this time..

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and show some code examples....

However, with that said, it may be a caching issue with your images and their server.
I did see that the path to the image (http://www.jeancharlesbarthelet.com/autre/logo.jpg) does serve up the image correctly. Perhaps revisit thie tomorrow?

When did you upload it to your server? if your hosting company uses akamai to cache it could take up to 6 hours to be seen globally...